# I have having Array Index Out Of Bound Error in this code

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, runtime-error, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

HERE IS THE JAVA CODE.HAVING ARRAY INDEX OUT OF BOUND ERROR ON RUNTIME.
i don't know what to do. I have tried every possible solution for this.
This is the error i am getting "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at QuizPG1.(QuizPG1.java:90)
at QuizPG1$3.run(QuizPG1.java:330)"

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class QuizPG1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
      String questions[][]=new String [10][5];
      String answers [][]=new String [10][1];
      String userans[][]=new String[10][1];
      public static int timer = 15;
      public static int answerGiven = 0;
      public static int count = 0;
      public static int score = 0;
      String name;
    public QuizPG1(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        initComponents();
        setSize(950,750);
        setLocation(500,150);
        
        questions[0][0]="What is the general purpose of JAVA VIRTUAL MACHINE(JVM)?";
        questions[0][1]="Compile Java Code";
        questions[0][2]="Execute Java Code";  //correct 
        questions[0][3]="Debug Java Code";
        questions[0][4]="Package Java Code";
        
        questions[1][0]="Which keyword is used to define constant variable in JAVA?";
        questions[1][1]="final";   //correct
        questions[1][2]="const";
        questions[1][3]="var";
        questions[1][4]="static";
        
        
        questions[2][0]="In JAVA which access modifier provides the widest visibility?";
        questions[2][1]="private";
        questions[2][2]="default";
        questions[2][3]="protected";
        questions[2][4]="public";  //correct
        
        questions[3][0]="Which is the correct syntax to create an object of a class named 'My Class'?";
        questions[3][1]="object MyClass = new object;";
        questions[3][2]="MyClass obj = create MyClass();";
        questions[3][3]="MyClass obj = new MyClass();";   //correct
        questions[3][4]="object obj = new MyClass;";
        
        questions[4][0]="Which data type is used to store a single Unicode character in JAVA?";
        questions[4][1]="char";  //correct
        questions[4][2]="string";
        questions[4][3]="character";
        questions[4][4]="unicode";
        
        questions[5][0]="Which statement is used to exit a loop in JAVA?";
        questions[5][1]="halt";
        questions[5][2]="stop";
        questions[5][3]="end";
        questions[5][4]="break";  //correct
        
        questions[6][0]="Which of the following is not a primitive data type in JAVA?";
        questions[6][1]="int";
        questions[6][2]="float";
        questions[6][3]="boolean";
        questions[6][4]="object";  //correct
        
        questions[7][0]="Which JAVA loop is guaranteed to execute at least once?";
        questions[7][1]="while";
        questions[7][2]="do-while";  //correct
        questions[7][3]="for";
        questions[7][4]="for-each";
        
        questions[8][0]="Which method is called automatically when an object is created from a class?";
        questions[8][1]="start()";
        questions[8][2]="initialize()";
        questions[8][3]="main()";
        questions[8][4]="constructor()";  //correct

        
        questions[9][0]="Which JAVA keyword is used to explicitly raise an exception?";
        questions[9][1]="raise";
        questions[9][2]="throw";   //correct
        questions[9][3]="exception";
        questions[9][4]="try";   
        
        answers[0][1]="Execute Java Code";
        answers[1][1]="final";
        answers[2][1]="public";
        answers[3][1]="MyClass obj = new MyClass();";
        answers[4][1]="char";
        answers[5][1]="break";
        answers[6][1]="object";
        answers[7][1]="do-while";
        answers[8][1]="constructor()";
        answers[9][1]="throw";
        
        buttonGroup1.add(opt1);
        buttonGroup1.add(opt2);
        buttonGroup1.add(opt3);
        buttonGroup1.add(opt4);
        submit.setEnabled(false);
        add(submit);
        start(count);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }

    QuizPG1() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
 private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
     //   DefaultTableModel tb = (DefaultTableModel) tablemodel1.getModel();
        repaint();
        
        answerGiven = 1;
        if (buttonGroup1.getSelection()== null){
               userans[count][0]="";
           }else{
               userans[count][0]=buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand();
           }
        if(count == 8){
            next.setEnabled(false);
            submit.setEnabled(true);
        }
        count++;
        start(count);
    }                                    

    private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        answerGiven = 1;
        if (buttonGroup1.getSelection()==null){
               userans[count][0]="";
           }else{
               userans[count][0]=buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand();
           }
             for(int i=0 ; i<userans.length;i++){
                 if(userans[i][0].equals(answers[i][1])){
                     score += 10;
                 }
             }
             setVisible(false);
             new Score(name,score);
             //SCOREtf.setText(score);
                 
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        
        String time = "Time Left:"+ timer + "seconds";
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,25));
        if (timer > 0){
           g.drawString(time, 900, 500);    
        }else{
            g.drawString("Times Up!!", 900, 500);   
        }
       timer--;
       
       try{
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           repaint();
       }  catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(QuizPG1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
       if (answerGiven == 1){
           answerGiven = 0;
           timer = 15;
       }else if (timer < 0) {
           
           if(count == 8){
            next.setEnabled(false);
            submit.setEnabled(true);
         } 
           if(count == 9){  //submit button
               if(count < userans.length){
             if (buttonGroup1.getSelection()==null){
               userans[count][0]="";
           }else{
               userans[count][0]=buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand();
           }
       }
              
             for(int i=0 ; i<userans.length;i++){
                 if(userans[i][0]!= null && userans[i][0].equals(answers[i][1])){
                     score += 10;
                 }
             }
             setVisible(false);
              new Score(name,score);
         } else{      // next button
           
           if (buttonGroup1.getSelection()==null){
               userans[count][0]="";
           }else{
               userans[count][0]=buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand();
           }
           count++;
           start(count); 
           }
       }
    
    }
   
    public void start(int count){
        qno.setText(""+ (count +1)+".");
        question.setText(questions[count][0]);
        opt1.setText(questions[count][1]);
        opt1.setActionCommand(questions[count][1]);
        
        opt2.setText(questions[count][2]);    
        opt2.setActionCommand(questions[count][2]);
        
        opt3.setText(questions[count][3]);        
        opt3.setActionCommand(questions[count][3]);
        
        opt4.setText(questions[count][4]);
        opt4.setActionCommand(questions[count][4]);
        
        buttonGroup1.clearSelection();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(QuizPG1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(QuizPG1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(QuizPG1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(QuizPG1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new QuizPG1("user").setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton next;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton opt1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton opt2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton opt3;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton opt4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel qno;
    private javax.swing.JLabel question;
    private javax.swing.JButton submit;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I tried this piece of code in paint method.

````
for(int i = 0; i < userans.length; i++){
    if(userans[i][0] != null && userans[i][0].equals(answers[i][1])){
        score += 10;
    }
}```

But it is still giving error.So i removed that amendment from my original code. Please provide me the solution.
The program is simple but on runtime I am having the Array index out of bound error.
````

Comment: this means you are trying to access the second element of an array which has zero or one element. Also, for future reference, try and keep the code as minimal as possible. There's no need for such lengthy code to reproduce this issue, is there?

Comment: replace this code answers[0][1]="Execute Java Code";   with answer[0][0]...note : there is no index 0,1 or 9,1 for array answer[10][1]  as size is only 1 .

Comment: you must be aware that indexes start at `0` and so can only go up to `length-1`  - so, for example, if you instantiate an array as `int[] array = new int[1];` - only one element - the only valid index is `0` and you will get that error if trying to access (read or set) `array[1]`